# бинарный "operator/" имеет слишком много параметров

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Выдаёт ошибку (бинарный "operator/" имеет слишком много параметров)

```
class Lamp
{
private:
    float Pn, Un, U;
public:
...
    float RawP() { return (U * Pn / Un); }
    float operator/(Lamp a, Lamp b);
};

float operator/(Lamp a, Lamp b)  
{   
    float tmp;   
    tmp = a.RawP() / b.RawP();
    return tmp;   
} 

int main()
{
float s;
...
s = Arr[j] / Arr[k];
}
```

Comment: Укажите спецификатор `friend`.

Answer (score 1):

Бинарный оператор, являющийся нестатическим членом класса должен принимать только один аргумент - второй. Первым будет `this`.

Можно вообще выкинуть оператор из класса, тогда он потеряет доступ к приватным членам, но в твоём случае они и не используются.

Ну и чтобы выкинуть оператор из класса, но одновременно предоставить ему доступ к приватным членам, надо объявить его дружественным классу (`friend`).

Comment: *"Если поменять его на статический"* `static` вроде не сработает, но можно вместо него приписать `friend` (не вынося определение из класса).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, действительно - static компилятор не ест: https://ideone.com/MzC6nj - _`prog.cpp:7:42: error: ‘static float Lamp::operator/(Lamp, Lamp)’ must be either a non-static member function or a non-member function`._ А мне почему-то казалось, что можно... С шарпом что ли попутал? Но там только статики и выбора нет. В общем, убрал из ответа про static.

Comment: Дык можно просто написать `friend` вместо `static`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так про friend у меня последний абзац.

Comment: У вас там "выкинуть из класса", а можно еще оставить его внутри класса и одновременно сделать `friend`. Или вы это и имели в виду?..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, давай по оставшимся абзацам. 1. Убрать аргумент и использовать this. 2. Сделать не членом класса, в классе ничего не писать. 3. Оператор по-прежнему не член класса, но в классе он прописан с friend - как раз то, что ты предлагаешь. Друзья же не являются членами.

Comment: Короче, я вот это предлагал: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/y2mDsx По идее да, он не член класса, даже если определен в теле класса.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну ты и тело внутрь утащил, а я думал его снаружи оставить. Кстати, не знал, что так можно.